# How to use a color buffer in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: colors, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am a bit confused on how to draw color using a color buffer. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261651/opengl-es-2-color-buffer-not-working) and made my shader the same as shown in the post's accepted answer. I then used the code:

```
mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(Shader, "vColor");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

ByteBuffer cb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(color.length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT);
cb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
colorBuffer = cb.asFloatBuffer();
colorBuffer.put(color);
colorBuffer.position(0);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
GLES20.glBufferSubData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, colorBuffer.capacity(), colorBuffer);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, 4,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, 0);
```

in attempt to draw the color.

The shape displayed the color I was trying to draw but it faded out the color across the shape like this:

[image]

If someone could tell me what's going wrong and how I could get the shape to be all the same color, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rabbid76 for helping me find the mistake.

Instead of 4 elements total in the color array, there needs to be 16, an RGBA value for each vertex. (4 elements of the array are used to make one RGBA value.)